# Any Dijit component is rendered as TextField

Tags: dojo

Please find my code which intents to develop a Form. Help me in understanding why the CheckBox and NumberSpinner are rendered as TextFields.

I have imported all the required classes and dojo config attribute is configured properly

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri=`enter code here`"http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@include file="/webclient/admin/jspf/NotificationOperations.jspf" %>
<!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webclient/map/js/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script>
        require([
            "dojo/parser",
            "dijit/form/CheckBox",
            "dijit/form/NumberSpinner",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(parser){
            parser.parse();
        });
</script>
<%@include file="/webclient/common/jspf/jsUtility.jspf" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <body class="claro">

    <style>
            @import "/webclient/common/js/dojo/dgrid/css/skins/claro.css";
            h2 {
                margin: 12px;
            }
            .heading {
                font-weight: bold;
                padding-bottom: 0.25em;
            }
            .ui-widget{
                margin: 10px;
            }
    </style>

    <table width="100%" height="100%">  
    <tr><td>
            <div id="DomainMapContainer" >          
            <tr class="spacer"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>         
            <tr><td>

                <form id="addProfile" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-props='encType:"multipart/form-data", action:"/prov/createRFC2544TestProfile.do?action=createRFC2544TestProfile", method:"POST", target:"formSubmitIframe"'>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="profileName">Profile Name</label></td>
                            <td>                            
                                <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" data-dojo-props='id:"profileName", name:"profileName", required:"true"'/>
                            </td>                                   
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="comments">Comments</label></td>
                            <td>                            
                                <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextArea" data-dojo-props='id:"comments", name:"comments", rows:"5", cols:"40"'/>
                            </td>                                   
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="frameSize">Frame Size</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>                            
                                        <td><label for="cb_1"><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" id="cb_1" name="cb_1" value="64" checked/> 64</label></td>
                                        <td><label for="cb_2"><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" id="cb_2" name="cb_2" value="128"/> 128</label></td>

                                 </table>
                            </td>                                   
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><label> Throughput Test</label></legend>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="tTestDuration">Test Duration</label></td>
                                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestDuration" value="60" data-dojo-props="smallDelta:1, constraints:{min:1,max:600,places:0}" name="tTestDuration"/>(Seconds)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="tTestMinFrameRate">Minimum Frame Rate</label></td>
                                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestMinFrameRate" value="0" data-dojo-props="smallDelta:1, constraints:{min:1,max:10000,places:0}" name="tTestMinFrameRate"/>(Mbps)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="tTestMaxFrameRate">Maximum Frame Rate</label></td>
                                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestMaxFrameRate" value="100" data-dojo-props="smallDelta:1, constraints:{min:1,max:10000,places:0}" name="tTestMaxFrameRate"/>(Mbps)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="tTestStepSize">Step Size</label></td>
                                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestStepSize" value="5" data-dojo-props="smallDelta:1, constraints:{min:1,max:100,places:0}" name="tTestStepSize"/>(Mbps)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="tTestAcceptableLoss">Step Size</label></td>
                                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberSpinner" id="tTestAcceptableLoss" value="0" data-dojo-props="smallDelta:0.1, constraints:{min:0,max:10,places:0}" name="tTestAcceptableLoss"/>(%)</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>                     
                </form>             
            </td></tr>
            </div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing a few things here, first of all you're missing a closing `</tr>` tag when you close the "frame size" table. I suppose that it won't cause errors, but you can never be too sure.

You're also closing your `</head>` tag at the bottom of the page. You should close it before the `<body>` starts.

Then the real problem is that your widgets are not working because there are errors while parsing your HTML. The cause of the error is the "comments" text area. The correct module name you should use is `dijit/form/Textarea`, so the "a" of area should be in **lowercase**.

Besides that, you should also add the `dijit/form/Textarea` module to your list of modules (in your `require()` block).

If you did all that it should work, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9U5AB/